# PathTooLongException Xamarin Droid Project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.droid

I Created a Xamarin.Forms project with a long path, and while building it I get this error:

> "System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

I can't change my project path neither my project name, it has to have that specific name.

Can any one help we find a workaround this problem please?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The "GenerateJavaStubs" task failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371378/the-generatejavastubs-task-failed)

Comment: Why can't you change your project path? This is probably the only way to resolve this.

Comment: Well it dosen´t make much sense to me having to change my project path just because xamarin projects only allow 248 characters.

Comment: But thanks anyway xamarin got the best of me and i changed my project name to be shorter.

Answer (score 34):

Try adding this msbuild property in your project that will shorten the file/folder names on the obj directory

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <UseShortFileNames>True</UseShortFileNames>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or this to change the output folder to a one closer to the `C:\`

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\MyFolder\MyProj</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: UseShortFileNames didn't work for me, but changing the IntermediateOutputPath did

Comment: Like @Rawrgramming said, the latter solution did the job. First one however did not.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest temporary solution is to move your project to a drive's root folder to decrease the length of the path.